# OpenCV Python Assertion Failed

Tags: python, opencv3.0, opencv

I am trying to run opencv-python==3.3.0.10 on a macOS 10.12.6 to read from a file and show the video in a window. I have exactly copied the code from here http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html, section 'Playing' video from file.

The code runs correctly and shows the video, however after termination of the video it breaks the program, giving the following error:

> Assertion failed: (ec == 0), function unlock, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libcxx/libcxx-307.5/src/mutex.cpp, line 48.

Does anyone have any idea of what might cause this?

---

Code snippet for your convenience (edited to include some suggestions in the comment)

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: After reading frame, add `if ret == False: break`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did add that, but still does not fix the problem. I tried to put a flag after the loop while, and the program does not arrive there. It seems that it does not go out of the loop..

Comment: comment out the `cap.release()` function and use `while True: ...`. What's the output?

Comment: It gives me the same error. Apparently there is a related issue on GitHub for mac: https://github.com/dthpham/butterflow/issues/12

Comment: Ok, if I uncomment cv2.destroyAllWindows() it seems to stop crashing. Any ideas why?

Comment: Update, it stops crashing SOMETIMES....

Comment: In terminal `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" >> result.txt`. Post the file to pastebin.com, upload link here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158676/discussion-between-campello-and-zindarod).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question, but it looks like you're specifically running into a situation where the video completes playing without being interrupted. I *think* the issue is that the VideoCapture object is already closed by the time you get to `cap.release()`. I'd recommend putting the call to `release` inside of the `if` statement by the break.

I've not had time to experiment, but I normally follow this pattern:

```
reader = cv2.VideoCapture(<stuff>)
while True:
  success, frame = reader.read()
  if not success:
     break
```

I'd not had to call `release` explicitly in those contexts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did not solve the problem. It does break the loop but if crashes right after (anything after the loop is not executed)

Comment: Ok, if I uncomment cv2.destroyAllWindows() it seems to stop crashing. Any ideas why?

Comment: What about using `cv2.namedWindow('frame')` at the beginning of the script?